# padding not working on input type radio

Tags: html, css

Padding property not working for radio button, it is only working in IE. fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/yvHPn/

```
<head>
<style>

body {margin:0; padding:0}
.radio input{ padding-left:20px;}

</style>

</head>

<body>
<div class="radio">

<input type="radio" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the padding only in .radio class like so

`.radio { padding-left:20px;}`